# Visual Studio Code error "The Flutter Daemon failed to start" .flutter_tool_state is being used by another process

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I have not used VSC for some days and when I started it today I got this error "The Flutter Daemon failed to start" and the problem that I see in the log is

```
[10:50:06 PM] [FlutterDaemon] [Error] Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'C:\Users\gusta\AppData\Roaming\.flutter_tool_state' (OS Error: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

, errno = 32)
#0      _File.throwIfError (dart:io/file_impl.dart:629:7)
#1      _File.openSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:473:5)
#2      _File.writeAsBytesSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:598:31)
#3      _File.writeAsStringSync (dart:io/file_impl.dart:622:5)
#4      ForwardingFile.writeA…
```

I can `flutter run` my application successfully.

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?

I've tried uninstalling several (but not all) components and reinstalling, rebooting, updating Flutter, etc. The error remains unchanged.

Comment: Q: You've tried rebooting your workstation - good.  Have you tried manually deleting "C:\Users\gusta\AppData\Roaming\.flutter_tool_state"?

Comment: The problem went away as mistereously as it showed up. Didn't install anything, didn't run any specific command, I didn't even restart the computer and ... now everything works. Sorry people for wasting your time...